# Dump SEXP structure to console

Tags: c, r

I am working with R internals interface in C. I need to analyze contents of SEXP from C but I don't know the exact SEXP structure. Is there an easy way (or some existing code) that I can dump an SEXP to the console or file in terms of the low-level C objects?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "contents"? E.g. what is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an internal function that you can call from R called `inspect`, e.g.

```
x <- list(1, 2, 3)
.Internal(inspect(x))
```

This gives

```
@7fd37292f970 19 VECSXP g0c3 [NAM(2)] (len=3, tl=0)
  @7fd370b9bd28 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @7fd370b9bcf8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
  @7fd370b9bcc8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 3
```

You could call it from C / C++ with something like:

```
#define R_NO_REMAP

#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

void inspect(SEXP x) {
    SEXP inspectCall = PROTECT(Rf_lang2(Rf_install("inspect"), x));
    SEXP dotInternalCall = PROTECT(Rf_lang2(Rf_install(".Internal"), inspectCall));
    Rf_eval(dotInternalCall, R_GlobalEnv);
    UNPROTECT(2);
}
```

You could also take a look at `Rf_PrintValue`, which is a mechanism for calling `print()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is mostly what I need.